# Dependency management in ROS2: CMakeLists.txt, package.xml, colcon build, make ...?

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently trying to understand the build system used by ROS2 and one thing I can't wrap my head around is the dependency management. Following [this](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber/#add-dependencies) tutorial, dependencies are added using  tags in package.xml. But for building the code, cmake's find_package() is used? Why do I need both? And what benefit is `colcon build` adding here, can't I just build the package using `make`?

Second, what's the prefered way to install dependencies? Take for example [this](https://github.com/klintan/ros2_usb_camera) package. According to its package.xml file it requires - among others - the package `camera_info_manager`. How do I install it? Does ROS2 ship with a package manager that allows installation of packages from remote source (like `npm install` or `vcpkg install`)? Can `rosdep` do the job or do I have to run `sudo apt-get install ros-eloquent-camera-info-manager` and cross my fingers that all packages I need are in the dpkg source?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360396/dependency-management-in-ros2:-cmakelists.txt,-package.xml,-colcon-build,-make-...?/) by [eloquent-fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/56547/eloquent-fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-08-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-26**:\

> Why do I need both?

Related I believe (although for ROS 1, but the same/similar infrastructure is used): #q217475 and #q215059.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> dependencies are added using  tags in package.xml. But for building the code, cmake's find_package() is used?

In order to be able to automate packaging as well as determine inter-package dependencies those need to be declared in a machine readable format. That is why they are present in the manifest files `package.xml`.

In CMake you need to find other packages. If the names of your build dependency names align perfectly with the names of the CMake config files you might be able to use convenience functions like [ament_auto_find_build_dependencies](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/cba8e43848ef403f422e147480d04460e474be2a/ament_cmake_auto/cmake/ament_auto_find_build_dependencies.cmake#L34). But in reality there are often mismatches between rosdep key names (the ones in the `package.xml` file) and the CMake config name. Therefore it is very common for them to be reiterated in CMake.

> And what benefit is `colcon build` adding here, can't I just build the package using `make`?

Any ROS package (which in ROS 2 could any build system like CMake, Python setuptools, etc.) can be build using its native build tool. So yes, you can invoke just `cmake && make && make install` on a ROS package using CMake (even if it uses `ament_cmake` or in ROS 1 `catkin`).

The "problem" with this approach is scalability. First, if you want to build multiple packages you need to manually determine in which order you need to build them. Second, if you want to build more than one package it will require a lot of manual labor. Pretty much all `colcon` is doing for you is figuring out the dependency graph and invoke the necessary commands to build each package based on the build system it uses (while also leveraging parallelism where possible to speed up the process).

> According to its package.xml file it requires - among others - the package `camera_info_manager`. How do I install it? Does ROS2 ship with a package manager that allows installation of package from remote source?

If there are binary packages for the platform you are interested in (e.g. Ubuntu) you can install those. E.g. for Ubuntu we create `deb`s which you can install using `apt`. For Windows Microsoft builds chocolatey packages which you can install with `choco`. So ROS uses existing package managers rather than inviting its own.

Beside that you can always build dependencies from source if either binary packages aren't available on your platform or you want a different version. When adding one dependency to your workspace it might require additional recursive dependencies. `rosinstall_generator` is a tool which helps you to get the source of all recursive dependencies so that you can build them from source.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) on 2020-08-27**:
Maybe offtopic, but I am curious.

> So ROS uses existing package managers rather than inviting its own.

With `rosinstall_generator`, `vcstool`, `colcon` and `rosdep` one can build its own package manager for ROS2. A primitive package manager for ROS2 could look something like this:
https://gist.github.com/lukicdarkoo/d03196b15367b804b27c142dad8644e9

Is there is any specific reason it is not done already? Of course, there is `apt`, but with ROS' package manager, one could install packages on unsupported operating systems.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-08-27**:
There are many many corner cases in package managers. How do you recover from errors? How do you check versions and make sure it's reproducible on two different machines? And that requires you to build from source for every package on every deployment which can take a long time for a large installation. And how do you upgrade a specific package?

There are a lot of package management tools out there and they have evolved and grown. We have support for apt, gentoo, openembedded, chocolaty, conda, snaps, docker images, and soon rpms. And support building from source on almost any platform. We do this by having the low level meta information available and tools that can leverage that and build on each other. A package manager is not something that's specific to robotics, and consequently we shouldn't reinvent the wheel, but learn from the many decades of development which have gone into the existing package managers and leverage their expertise.

**Comment by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) on 2020-08-27**:
I am not arguing that ROS' package manager supposed to replace the `apt` and similar but to complement them. There are many packages that are not published to `apt`, or there is no specific package version available, or the package is available for a new ROS distro even though it is compatible.

> And how do you upgrade a specific package?

Use `vcstool` to pull a new code and rebuild it with `colcon` (maybe also re-run `rosinstall_generator` and `rosdep`). Or, delete the package and install it again.

> How do you check versions

`rosinstall_generator` generates `.repo` with the branch names, maybe one could specify hashes instead.

> How do you recover from errors?

But I see your point. The error recovery may be the hardest to implement. It is very hard to guarantee the packages can be compiled smoothly on different operating systems.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-28**:
The build-pkgs-from-source helper is a nice idea @lukicdarkoo, but tbh, I'd rather we avoid having people build packages from source as much as possible. Depending on `rosdep` to install dependencies is possible, but it's not sufficiently robust, as many pkgs don't state their dependencies properly. In addition, too many users have development environments which are not clean or sane, leading to all sorts of problems.

Installing pkgs using `apt` is much more of a hardened process. As @tfoote mentions, platform pkg managers have decades of development behind them, which especially covers all sorts of corner cases and tries to maintain transactional application of updates (at the package level, not across perhaps). We shouldn't want to replicate all of that.